# Questions with file upload

Tags: php

I am working on something with file upload this might be a stupid question and people might down vote it but i want to understand what I am doing. I am still new to this. Ok when it says `$filename=filenameSafe($_FILES['uploadXXXX']['name']);` is the where i would out the name of the file that has the http or would it be the folder that the upload goes or the index that has the functions being called. Same as this line

```
    $fileType=$_FILES["uploadXXXX"]["type"];
    if (in_array($_FILES["uploadXXXX"]["type"],$aryImages)){
        createThumb($fileType,$_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'],$filename,10
```

I am getting a little bit confused. Same with I have a database name tblFile but I am not to sure where to put that at either.  This is the other line of code

```
elseif (in_array($_FILES["uploadFile"]["type"],$aryDocs)){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'],
"/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/YOURFULLPATH/".$filename);

$aryColumns=array("sessionID"=>$curSess,"fileName"=>$filename,"fileType"=>$fileType,"thumbFileName"=>$thumbFilename,"dateCreated"=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        dbInsert($filename,$aryColumns,$_FILES["uploadXXXX"]["type"]);
    }
```

Can someone might be able to help me understand this so I will not be so confused with it.Thank for everyone who reads this.

Comment: Ohh the folder that everything is in is called filename. In this folder it has the upload folder the index.php and the uploads.php.

Comment: My guess is that the `filenameSafe` is a function that takes the current filename and checks so it not already exists or perhaps cleans out any unwanted characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line gets the filetype of the file (PDF, Doc, JPEG, PNG, etc.):

```
$fileType=$_FILES["uploadXXXX"]["type"];
```

This line checks whether the filetype is in the list of allowed image formats, which is an array named `$aryImages`:

```
if (in_array($_FILES["uploadXXXX"]["type"],$aryImages)){
    createThumb($fileType,$_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'],$filename,10);
```

If the file is *not* an image, then this next line checks whether it is a document. If it is, then the uploaded document is moved to `/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/YOURFULLPATH/` and something happens with the database:

```
elseif (in_array($_FILES["uploadFile"]["type"],$aryDocs)){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'],
"/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/YOURFULLPATH/".$filename);

$aryColumns=array("sessionID"=>$curSess,"fileName"=>$filename,"fileType"=>$fileType,"thumbFileName"=>$thumbFilename,"dateCreated"=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        dbInsert($filename,$aryColumns,$_FILES["uploadXXXX"]["type"]);
    }
```

I'm not sure why that database part is only applicable for the document format, though, and not for the images. I would think that it should be *outside* of the `if` loop.

---

If you don't understand how the code works, I don't think you should use it. I suggest you try and write the code yourself, as you won't have this problem.

Comment: ok so with the $fileType=$_FILES["uploadXXXX"]["type"]; it would be $fileType=$_FILES["upload.php"]["type"]; being the fact the the uploads folder has the function for the jpeg in it.then with the uploadFils would also be the uploads.php and then the yourfullpath would that be filename or the tblFile that is what my database is called.

Comment: In `$_FILES['uploadXXXX']`, `uploadXXXX` is the `name=` attribute of your `<input type="file" name="uploadXXXX" />` element in your HTML page. As for your database, I can't answer that. I don't know what `dbInsert()` even is.

Comment: ok thank you blender I am still a little confused but kinda understanding.

Comment: That's why I suggested that you try and write this yourself. When you do, you learn how things work ;)

Comment: To be honest I am flying through all this php and everything is getting me confusing.